# Adding Dependencies in pom.xml

Tags: maven-2, jdbc, jar, m2eclipse

I am creating a project which will have oracle 10g/11g at its back end. For that I need ojdbc.jar. The problem is whenever I add ojdbc14.jar and save in pom.xml (I use m2eclipse plugin)it gives me a weird error '**Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.4.0:compile**'. whenever I remove this jar file from pom.xml the error disappears. I don't get why this is happening ??
What is the solution for this ???

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of your pom.xml?

Comment: I tried following but still it gives me same error.    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
     <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
     <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: you can find it @http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22com.oracle%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ojdbc14%22

Comment: Open pom.xml, click on the entry for ojdbc14 under dependencies, open properties and change the 'type' from bundle to jar. This should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to share your `pom` dependency. The `pom` dependency for Oracle 10g is

```
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
  <!-- use the 10g drivers which are surprisingly largely bug free -->
  <version>10.0.2.0</version>
```

Also if you are deploying this in a server environment, it is better to put the driver `jar` in the `lib` folder of the server and provide scope as `provided`.

So the following things could go wrong.

1. Do you have a specific scope qualifier in your `pom`?
2. Any typos?
3. Do you have a local maven artifacts like `artifactory`?